# Sql server query that is recursive in multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I've a table structure as follows with sample data as follows
Name: User

```
User   Region
Sam    USA    
Meyer  NA    
Ying   Japan    
Yang   Asia
```

I also have another table, with the region and the countries

Name: Region

```
       Region Country         RegionList    
        USA     America            
        NA       NULL          USA            
        NA      Canada            
        NA      Mexico            
        Japan   Japan
        Asia     NULL         Central        
        Asia      NULL         East        
        Central  India        
        East     Dubai
        Central  Japan
```

How do you write a SQL server query to list each user and the corresponding countries, that he/she represents?

Like:

```
Sam   America
Meyer America
Meyer Canda
Meyer Mexico
Ying  Japan
Yang  Japan
Yang  India
Yang  Dubai
```

Comment: Who are you and what have you done to my database schema?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your Region table is potentially infinitely many levels deep, you can use a [Common Table Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). See [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
WITH UserRegions (username, region, country)
AS
(
    -- Anchor member definition
    SELECT u.[user] AS username, r.regionlist AS region, r.country
    FROM [User] u
    JOIN Region r
        ON u.Region = r.Region
    UNION ALL
    -- Recursive member definition
    SELECT ur.username, r.regionlist AS region, r.country
    FROM Region r
    INNER JOIN UserRegions AS ur
        ON r.Region = ur.Region
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT username, country
FROM UserRegions
WHERE country IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY username
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ca9de/8

Comment: For a given user names, finding the list of countries is something I already did. Looking to find for every user, the list of countries that he/she represents.

Comment: the question appears to show that he cares about recursion, but his sample results appear to say he doesn't.

Comment: Thanks flup. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JOIN to get your desired results

```
SELECT user, isNull(Country,RegionList) Country
FROM user
    JOIN region ON users.region = region.region
ORDER BY user, Country
```

if you want to return all users even if they don't have any countries then you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN

```
SELECT user, isNull(isNull(Country,RegionList),'No countries') Country
FROM user
    LEFT OUTER JOIN region ON users.region = region.region
ORDER BY user, Country
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the needs of his schema, since it has some recursion in the Region table.

Comment: @KyleHale the results provided don't suggest recursion is relevant.

Comment: haha are you both having a downvote war? Anyways, Matt's answer solves the problem. No recursion is necessary. +1.

Comment: How would this query return Yang, Dubai? (Hint: It won't.)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the explicit schema and sample data you provided:

```
select
user, isnull(region.country, r2.country) as Country 
from 
user
left join 
region 
on user.region = region.region
left join
region r2
on r2.region = region.regionlist
```